# Getting key with largest value from TypeScript Map

Tags: typescript

If I have a Map, defined like so:

```js
let map: Map<string, number> = new Map();

map.set("a", 12);
map.set("b", 124);
map.set("c", 14);
map.set("d", 155);
```

How would I get the key of the biggest value, in this case, the output would be `"d"`

I've tried a few answers that work with Object's(i.e `{}`) but none of those work since they access the object using `obj[key]`.

Typescript Playground link with the code: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDgLggWXgHgM5gE4EsB2A5gDQT4CuUARiNgHwQC8ZIA7ivABQCUA3ALAAoIbDgA6DOE4AiGNNIBGAEx8R8CVOlV5EZQBZVg0RrAyAxjoUGBR9ZNPSAJpYCsLvkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), this could be done as follows:

```
Array.from(map.entries()).reduce((a, b) => a[1] < b[1] ? b : a)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach

- Convert it to an array of key/value pairs
- Sort the array by the value
- Extract the second item of the first pair

Like so

```
let map: Map<string, number> = new Map();

map.set("a", 12);
map.set("b", 124);
map.set("c", 14);
map.set("d", 155);

const key = Array.from(map).sort((a, b) => (a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : 1))[0][0];

console.log(key);
```